# Can I get a Visa for Nepal in its border with India?

Tags: visas, india, nepal

I'm an European citizen with a visa for India that allows for multiple entries. I understand that, that doesn't allow me to enter Nepal. If I go to Nepal's border, can I get a Nepal's visa there? What would it take?

On a related note (although maybe off topic) is it even worth to go there now? With the recent earthquakes, is the situation suitable for tourists?

Comment: Please consider deleting the second part of your question as it is currently too broad.

Comment: As for your second part, almost everything except those lives we regrettably lost are restored now. I have a few friends who went there recently (not sure about the Himalaya region though).

Comment: For a country like Nepal that depend mainly on tourists, now is the best time for tourists to visit to give a push to their economy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**, [visas are available on arrival](http://www.nepalimmigration.gov.np/article/44/visa-info.html) at most major land crossings, including those with India, for citizens of all EU countries.

[Submitting an application online](http://online.nepalimmigration.gov.np/tourist-visa) in advance will speed up things considerably.